# Using setcookie() causing serialize & and unserialize not to work in PHP

Tags: php, serialization, cookies, web, null

I am trying to pass an array between 2 pages for a website, I am using setcookie() and serialize() to do so. It seems to be coded correctly, but is not working

First File:

```
setcookie('iconHumans', serialize($iconHumans));
setcookie('iconRatings', serialize($iconRatings));
setcookie('iconIDs', serialize($iconID), time()+3600);
setcookie('curIcon', 0);
```

Second File:

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE['iconIDs'])){
        echo "unserializing: <br>";
        $iconHumans = unserialize($_COOKIE['iconHumans']);
        $iconRatings = unserialize($_COOKIE['iconRatings']);
        $iconIDs = unserialize($_COOKIE['iconIDs']);
        $curIcon = $_COOKIE['curIcon'];
    }
```

When i use vardump to show the variables:

```
echo"This should be the Ratings: <br>";
var_dump($iconRatings);
```

Null is returned for all 3 even thought before serialization the arrays were intact

but, for curIcon 0 is printed out properly

Any explanation why this isn't working would be very helpful
I also tried Json_encode/decode and that did not work either

I am using firefox

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the size of the serialized data? A cookie can hold max 4 kb

Comment: im not sure but this is one of the arrays that isnt working:
array(7) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(1) "7" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(2) "16" [4]=> string(1) "6" [5]=> string(2) "12" [6]=> string(1) "5" }

is that too big?

Comment: `serialize` only accepts one argument, so your `time()+3600` line isn't valid.

Comment: Actually i just figured out that is not the issue; i changed the arrays to only hold one thing each and it still did not work.... But thank you for your knowledge

Comment: Seems legit. Next: both script work under the same domain?

Comment: Yes Mark I realized that and fixed it on my program and it still does not work, i have reposted the new code

Comment: yea they are both on my localhost

Comment: You might want to consider using `$_SESSION` instead - it's simpler and a bit more secure

Comment: What's browser dev console saying. Does the cookie arrive at the browser? Check Request/Response headers..

Comment: Hm, are magic quotes in cookies rearing their ugly heads?

Comment: $_Session seems to be working! ill confirm once im finished coding

Comment: Yea thats working, thank you Bojangles, your a modern day hero.
This can be marked as answered
The solution has to do with setcookie altering the data for some reason

Comment: Wrikken what did you mean